# JavaScript Matching Similar Patterns Over Multiple Lines Using Lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to come up with regex block that will extract tables from a cucumber sample using javascript. Sample cucumber is below

```
Feature: Sample Feature File

   Scenario: An international coffee shop must handle currencies
      Given the price list for an international coffee shop
      | product | currency | price |
      | coffee  | EUR      | 1     |
      | donut   | SEK      | 18    |
      When I buy 1 coffee and 1 donut
      Then should I pay 1 EUR and 18 SEK

   Scenario Outline: eating
      Given there are <start> cucumbers
      When I eat <eat> cucumbers
      Then I should have <left> cucumbers

      Examples:
      | start | eat | left |
      |  12   |  5  |  7   |
      |  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

the regular expression should return me the following in two matches like so

1)

```
  | product | currency | price |
  | coffee  | EUR      | 1     |
  | donut   | SEK      | 18    |
```

2)

```
  | start | eat | left |
  |  12   |  5  |  7   |
  |  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

Once I get the blocks I will split by line to get number of rows in table. In any case I have tried a negative look up expressions in an attempt to solve this. My effort is below

```
/(\|)[\s\S]*\|(?!\s+\|)/gm
```

however that returns

```
| product | currency | price |
      | coffee  | EUR      | 1     |
      | donut   | SEK      | 18    |
      When I buy 1 coffee and 1 donut
      Then should I pay 1 EUR and 18 SEK

   Scenario Outline: eating
      Given there are <start> cucumbers
      When I eat <eat> cucumbers
      Then I should have <left> cucumbers

      Examples:
      | start | eat | left |
      |  12   |  5  |  7   |
      |  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

if I remove the second scenario the regex works as expected and returns only

```
  | product | currency | price |
  | coffee  | EUR      | 1     |
  | donut   | SEK      | 18    |
```

any suggestions on where my regex is going wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `((?:\s*\|.*\|\s*)+)`?

Comment: almost that expression includes spaces either side but its closer, namely it has spaces from previous and next lines

Comment: trim the whitespaces after?

Comment: Here's a somewhat ridiculous solution using capture and replace https://regex101.com/r/Yqaajy/7

Comment: Try [`/^\s*\|.*\|(?:\s*[\r\n]\s*\|.*\|)*/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/lZ9HY9/1). Or a bit more [enhanced version](https://regex101.com/r/lZ9HY9/3).

Comment: `\s*((?:\s*\|.*\|\s*?)+)\s*` - updated version without whitespace from previous/next lines

Comment: looks good folks thanks for all the help with the above :)

Comment: @bhreinb See my pattern below explained and with a demo.

Answer (score 1):

The `[\s\S]*` pattern matches any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the last `|` in the string that has no 1+ whitespaces and `|` immediately to the right of the current position. Since the matches are searched for from left to right, it is only logical that you get a single match.

I suggest unrolling the pattern like

```
/^[^\S\r\n]*\|.*\|(?:[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+[^\S\r\n]*\|.*\|)*/gm
```

See [its demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lZ9HY9/3).

Note you may make it readable if you build it dynamically:

```js
var h = "[^\\S\r\n]*";     // horizontal whitespace block
var rx = new RegExp("^" +     // start of a line
      h + "\\|.*\\|" +        // hor. whitespace, |, 0+ chars other than line breaks, |
      "(?:" + h + "[\r\n]+" + // 0+ sequences of hor. whitespace, line breaks, 
      h + "\\|.*\\|)*",       // hor. whitespace, |, 0+ chars other than line breaks, |
      "gm"); // Global (find multiple matches) and multiline (^ matches line start)
var s = "Feature: Sample Feature File\r\n\r\n   Scenario: An international coffee shop must handle currencies\r\n      Given the price list for an international coffee shop\r\n      | product | currency | price |\r\n      | coffee  | EUR      | 1     |\r\n      | donut   | SEK      | 18    |\r\n      When I buy 1 coffee and 1 donut\r\n      Then should I pay 1 EUR and 18 SEK\r\n\r\n   Scenario Outline: eating\r\n      Given there are <start> cucumbers\r\n      When I eat <eat> cucumbers\r\n      Then I should have <left> cucumbers\r\n\r\n      Examples:\r\n      | start | eat | left |\r\n      |  12   |  5  |  7   |\r\n      |  20   |  5  |  15  |";
console.log(s.match(rx));
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace
- `\|` - a `|`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\|` - a `|`
- `(?:[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+[^\S\r\n]*\|.*\|)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace
  - `[\r\n]+` - 1 or more CR or/and LF symbols (if you want to only match 1 line break, use `(?:\r\n?|\n)` here)
  - `[^\S\r\n]*\|.*\|` - 0+ horizontal whitespace, `|`, any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, `|`